# LDAP for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ldap

Requires upload user information from Active Directory.

I found on the Internet a few additions that provide this opportunity: **multicorn** and **ldap_fdw**.

The problem is that I can not figure out how to filter the result

For example **multicorn** allows you to specify the directory where to search (*path*) and the object of the search (*objectClass*). But this is not enough. It is necessary to restrict the people who are in a particular group.

How to do it?

Comment: You want to search people in particular group ?

Comment: Also posted on .ru at http://stackoverflow.com/q/32138912/398670 . Constantine, please post a link to this question from your .ru copy to help people who find that one follow it to here.

Comment: Do you want to create PostgreSQL user accounts from LDAP (AD) users? Or do you need to copy more data? What kind of queries against LDAP will you run to get the data?

Comment: > You want to search people in particular group ?

 - Yes.

> Do you want to create PostgreSQL user accounts from LDAP (AD) users? 

 - Yes. But I do not want all users from AD. Only users in a particular group.

For example, all users belonging to a group of administrators, etc

Answer (score 0):

Postgres uses LDAP only to check password. You must still create roles with proper Postgres options, heritage and grants.

To create roles dynamically from LDAP rather than creating them manually without password, you can use a tool like [ldap2pg](https://ldap2pg.rtfd.io).

Using `ldap_fdw` or multicorn should not be useful for this. These extensions are meant to expose foreign data to APP, not to extend Postgres internals.

Cheers,